VS Code outDebug doesn't exist
So, I am a beginner in coding. I have used VS Code previously but never encountered this type of issue; can somebody help me in solving this?

Umm, since I am a newbie, I tried to fix it by watching video and exploring the web, but I could not discover the right method.

Is that the name of the program you are trying to compile? If it is then you likely have a compile error that you'd need to fix. If it is not then you have a configuration issue in vscode that you need to fix. Look at the launch.json file it offers to open for you.

Close the project you're working on. Then, generate a new one from scratch, compile and run. If this gives the same error, your installation has a problem. If not, you now have a working example which you can compare to the one that doesn't work. This has nothing to do with JSON, btw. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

@RetiredNinja
No, that's not the name of the program. It was showing a compiler path error and I fixed the path, and now the compiler is working I guess. But it's showing this error I searched that location, and there are no such folders on that location. I created one manually, still doesn't work.

https://medium.com/@usmanmehmood55/setup-guide-for-c-c-programming-on-vscode-b6047463dc1c

{
"id":"SaleDeliverDetail",
"Params":[{"Name":"PageNum","Value":"100"},
{"Name":"IsStruct" ,"Value":1},
{"Name":"IsReqFields" ,"Value":1},
{"Name":"hid","Value":"10103601"}//آی دی سند
]
}

How is this related to the question? How is this supposed to solve the problem? Code without explanation is considered a low quality answer. (If it was an answer at all...)
